# Find diagonal without cycle or diagonal

Tags: python, numpy, diagonal, index-error

I was trying to find the diagonal of matrix `b` without using cycle or diag. I got an error: `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`. Not sure how to fix this.

```
b = np.random.randint(low = 1, high = 11, size = (10,10))

print(list(map(lambda x: x[a.index(x)], a)))
```

Comment: You confused a and b ??

Comment: You right... After I fixed this, still not working :( any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The numpy ndarray object doesn't behave exactly like a python list, specifically, as the error specifies, it does not have an 'index' function. Here is one way to go around this:

You can first convert b from a numpy ndarray to a standard python list, in the following way:

```
b = b.tolist()
```

Then, the code you wrote would work.

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x[b.index(x)], b)))
```

Comment: I'm trying not to use cycle :(

Comment: @JuKa Ah I understand. I just fixed my answer, does this solve your problem?